# Window resize events and media queries do not fire when window height is changed at heights under 500px

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm working with a responsive design that includes vertical breakpoints.  I'm seeing that CSS media queries as well as window resize events do not fire once the window height is less than 500px.  This may seem like a fringe use case, but folks with disabilities do frequently adjust screen resolutions leaving less available height.  When the window height is less than 500px, horizontal resize events still fire, but not vertical ones.  I couldn't find any info on this, and I did lose some time trying to understand what I was seeing, so I thought I'd share the experience and ask if anyone knows anything about it.  I observed this behavior in IE10, Firefox, and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've supplied no code so it's hard to decipher exactly what's wrong. However, the following JSBin works fine for me in Chrome and is using both media queries (`max-height`) and `window.addEventListener('resize')` without problems under 500px.

http://jsbin.com/xumigo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  console.log(window.innerHeight);
});


@media (max-height:600px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
  body::before {
    content: '600px'
  }
}
@media (max-height:500px) {
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
  body::before {
    content: '500px'
  }
}
@media (max-height:400px) {
  body {
    background: orange;
  }
  body::before {
    content: '400px'
  }
}
@media (max-height:300px) {
  body {
    background: yellow;
  }
  body::before {
    content: '300px'
  }
}
@media (max-height:200px) {
  body {
    background: black;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  body::before {
    content: '200px'
  }
}
@media (max-height:100px) {
  body {
    background: gray;
    color: #000;
  }
  body::before {
    content: '100px'
  }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done @rgthree.  It was a local issue, and this helped me get to the root of the problem.  Thanks.